# keystone command not found

Tags: openstack, keystone, openstack-neutron

while running openstack-status I got this error..

/usr/bin/openstack-status: line 267: keystone: command not found

above

> == Keystone service ==
>
> openstack-keystone:                     inactive  (disabled on boot)
>
> openstack-nova-network:                 inactive  (disabled on boot)

[root@rd0-openstack keystone(keystone_admin)]# keystone-

keystone-manage       keystone-wsgi-admin   keystone-wsgi-public

so what else to check

Comment: keystone as a stand-alone client is not distributed anymore, superseded by `openstack` client. Maybe you're running an old version of openstack-status or a buggy one

Comment: yes i found that on bugzilla , no i m using Newton from rdo-project thanks for help ..

Answer (score 1):

openstack-status is still using 'keystone user list' which is depreciated it should use 'openstack user list' instead  please  update openstack-status binary to make it work.

use "vim +267 /usr/bin/openstack-status"

and replace  'keystone user-list'  with 'openstack user list'

or use below sed command to replace it accordingly.

sed -i 267s/'keystone user-list'/'openstack user list'/ /usr/bin/openstack-status

[keystone command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356219/keystone-command-not-found)